# Why WaitUntilObjectNotExists After Delete?

Tags: go, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-go

I am looking at the aws sdk-for-go developer guide to [delete an object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/v1/developer-guide/s3-example-basic-bucket-operations.html#s3-examples-bucket-ops-delete-bucket-item).

Sample Code

```
_, err = svc.DeleteObject(&s3.DeleteObjectInput{Bucket: aws.String(bucket), Key: aws.String(obj)})
if err != nil {
    exitErrorf("Unable to delete object %q from bucket %q, %v", obj, bucket, err)
}

err = svc.WaitUntilObjectNotExists(&s3.HeadObjectInput{
    Bucket: aws.String(bucket),
    Key:    aws.String(obj),
})
```

As seen above, the example calls the delete object API followed by wait till object does not exists
I have below questions related to this:

1. After calling the delete API why is it necessary to wait and check if it is deleted ?
2. How long does it wait for the check? (What is the max window ?). How frequently does it check?

Could not find anything in the AWS documentation which answers this.

Comment: I would assume that the DeleteObject operation is an operation with eventual consistency and that `WaitUntilObjectExists` is used until the consistency is achieved across all S3 data centers. If you want to control the wait period and max attempts, you can use the `WaitUntilObjectExistsWithContext` method.

Answer (score 1):

As the earlier answer mentioned, there seem to be fewer waiters in the v2 SDK compared to the v1 SDK. However, this may not have been a completely deliberate choice made by the authors of the SDK. There appear to be some other waiters that people have requested [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/issues/1148) and [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/issues/1111). If you see a waiter that is missing from the v2 SDK, it simply may not have been ported over yet.

Answer (score 0):

You'll be happy to know that in Go V2 no such waiter exists. It only supplies a waiter on object existence, which is what you need when creating a resource.